# Perturbation theory, eigenvalues and eigenvectors for degenerate case (1st order)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, notation, perturbation-theory

I was trying to understand the perturbation theory, but I was lost in the notation...

I have understood that I have to identify the unperturbed kets that are degenerated and find the matrix $V$, where $V_{mm'}=<m|V|m'>$ and |m>, |m'> are eigenstates that have the same eigenvalue.

Then I have to diagonalize $V$ and its eigenvalues are the energy-shifts at the first order.

But then I haven't understood which are "the related eigenstates at the first order".

If I find the eigenvectors related to the eigenvalues of $V$, they are the correct zero-th order kets that the perturbed kets approaches when the perturbation approaches to zero.. aren't they?

Which is the expression of the first-order eingenvectors? Is its correction $|r^{(1)}>=\sum_{k \neq D}\frac{ |k^{(0)}><k^{(0)}|V|r^{(0)}>}{E_D-H_0}$?

Comment: You get the *zeroth* order eigenstates from this procedure (which are the corresponding eigenvectors). The original basis of the eigenspace will not lead to continous behaviour of the eigenvalues when turning on the perturbation (which lifts the degeneracy).